# Under Win8.1, IE always asks me to make it the default browser

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, windows-8.1

I'm using Win8.1 and have set Firefox as default browser, also given all the standards it accepts (via default programs) but when I need to open some site in IE11, it always pesters me with the message "don't miss the browser that's been developped especially for Windows" (my translation, <del>see screenshot for message in german</del>).
There is a button "No thanks" but no way to say "and don't bother to ask me in future".

EDIT: No screenshot due to stupid points issues.

Answer (score 1):

It was like this in previous version, dont know about windows 8.1 but it must be in the IE settings

Go to IE "Internet options" then "Programs" and un-check the box , just like below

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I can't see that option under Win8.1.